# Binding Command withing a DataGridTemplateColumn

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, mvvm-light

I would like to bind a command ("EditOrCreateStudentCommand") to a button within a DataGridTemplateColumn.
The DataContext in this case is the StudentViewModel. This is defined in the Grid.

Within the DataTemplate I cannot execute the command (nothing happens).
Outside the template I can execute the command without problems. What could be the reason?

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding StudentViewModel}">
   <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Students}">
      <DataGrid.Columns>
         <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="*" />
         <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                  <Button Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.EditOrCreateStudentCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Grid}}"/>
               </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
         </DataGridTemplateColumn>
      </DataGrid.Columns>
   </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

I already looked at the other same questions on stackoverflow, but none of them solved this problem.

Comment: DataGrid columns are not part of the visual tree. You can use a binding proxy: https://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause of your problem is that the `DataGrid` template contains `Grid`. That why when you set the relative source, you will get the incorrect Grid. From the visual Tree view in the visual studio:

[image]

A possible solution to your problem is to add Name to the grid and refernce it by `ElementName` in the binding:

```
<Grid x:Name="StudentGrid" DataContext="{Binding StudentViewModel}">
   <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Students}">
      <DataGrid.Columns>
         <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="*" />
         <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                  <Button Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.EditOrCreateStudentCommand, ElementName=StudentGrid}"/>
               </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
         </DataGridTemplateColumn>
      </DataGrid.Columns>
   </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I hadn't thought of that!